# convert a unix timestamp to localtime

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unix-timestamp

How to multiply this with *1000 to get the unix timestamp converted to local timestamp?

I wrote this expression, but somehow the error message comes up with:

> The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any',
> 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

```
 x: [new Date(this.unixtimearray[i].time)]*1000,
```

In unixtimearray you get all the timestamps.
I expected dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss as a return value

Comment: Is this javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x: new Date(this.unixtimearray[i].time*1000)
```

If `this.unixtimearray[i].time` is a string:

```
x: new Date(parseInt(this.unixtimearray[i].time)*1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to multiply seconds by 1000 and then pass this value to Date(). Read comments in the code below for additional information

```js
// Unix timestamp (sec)
const unixTimestamp = 1598949817;

// Get date (sec * 1000 = millisec)
const date = new Date(unixTimestamp * 1000);

// log
console.log(date);

// And you can format your output string like this
// If you need to add leading zeros in date and month
// you can use construction presented below
var dateFormat = ('0' + date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) +"/"+ ('0' + (date.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) +"/"+ date.getUTCFullYear() + " " + date.getUTCHours() + ":" + date.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + date.getUTCSeconds();

// Log custom format
console.log(dateFormat);
```